# Check all checkboxes, when one checkbox is clicked in Android?

Tags: java, android, checkbox

The thing I'm trying is to check all those checkboxes, when "cbkomplet" is checked.
But it doesn't work.
Here's the code I have so far.

```
CheckBox repeatChkBx = ( CheckBox ) findViewById( R.id.cbkomplet );
        repeatChkBx.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {
                if ( isChecked )
                {
                    cbreg.isChecked();
                    cbtank.isChecked();
                    cbzoop.isChecked();
                    cbkom.isChecked();
                    cbmaske.isChecked();
                    cbbl.isChecked();
                    
                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to call `setChecked()`, not `isChecked()` on the dependent check boxes. You are simply testing if each of them is checked, then throwing away the result.

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setChecked(boolean)

Answer (score 2):

Use this code.

```
  chkbxAll = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbAll);
    chkbxOne = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkbxOne );
    chkbxTwo = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkbxTwo );
    chkbxThree = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkbxThree );
    chkbxFour = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkbxFour );

 chkbxAll .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new      
    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean 
          isChecked) {
            if (chkbxAll.isChecked()) {
                chkbxOne.setChecked(true);
                chkbxTwo.setChecked(true);
                chkbxThree.setChecked(true);
                chkbxFour.setChecked(true);
            }else {
                chkbxOne.setChecked(false);
                chkbxTwo.setChecked(false);
                chkbxThree.setChecked(false);
                chkbxFour.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `isChecked()` method, which returns a boolean to tell you if the checkbox is checked. Please use `setChecked()` instead, and pass in true or false.